# Why am I getting Unreachable code detected?

Tags: c#

The code:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
  if (ex is WebException)
  {
    wccfg.failedUrls++; //  i think you forgot this
    return csFiles;
  }
  else
  {
    throw new Exception("");
    wccfg.failedUrls++;
    return csFiles;
  }
}
```

On the second wccfg(another class) I see green line say Unreachable code detected.
Should I move this line above the throw new Exception line ?

Comment: You should run some trial code that does `throw new Exception("");` and see if that's something you'd ever want to maintain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because once you:

```
throw new Exception("");
```

No other code after that point will get executed.

So yes.  You either need a `return` or a `throw`, you can't have both.

There's also no reason to test what the Exception type is using an `if` block, as you can have multiple `catch` statements to do that.

Answer (score 4):

You getting the warning because none of the code after `throw new Exception("");` will be executed.

That belies the fact that your Exception handling code is, quite honestly, a mess. There are already ways to handle different types of Exceptions without catching a broad category and using the `is` keyword. You're also swallowing a potentially meaningful exception by throwing a new Exception with no details:

You may want to consider something more appropriate like:

```
catch(WebException ex)
{
    wccfg.failedUrls++;
    return csFiles
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    wccfg.failedUrls++;
    throw;
}
```

Comment: `+1` for this.  Though if you wanna get *really* picky, you might get a warning about the unused variable `ex`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this - it eliminates your error (because no code can execute after the Throw) and reduces duplication:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
  wccfg.failedUrls++;

  if (!(ex is WebException))
  {
    throw new Exception("");
  }
}

return csFiles;
```